# Why can't std::ostream be moved?

Tags: c++, c++11, iostream

Clearly, streams can't be copied. It should be possible to move streams. According to 27.9.1.11 [ofstream.cons] paragraph 4 it is possible to move construct an `std::ofstream` (the same is true for `std::ifstream`, `std::fstream`, and the `std::*stringstream` variants). For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

std::ofstream makeStream(std::string const& name) {
    return std::ofstream(name);
}

int main()
{
    std::ofstream out{ makeStream("example.log") };
}
```

Trying to move an `std::ostream`, e.g., to have a factory function creating an `std::ofstream`, an `std::ostringstream`, or some other stream according to a URN passed as argument doesn't work. `std::ostream` (well, the class template `std::basic_ostream` really) has a `protected` move constructor according to 27.7.3.1 [ostream].

Why can't `std::ostream` be moved itself?

Comment: What would you move the `std::ostream` to? You need to create an instance of the derived class, unless I'm misunderstanding you, and if you don't know the derived class at compile-time, how would the move work?

Comment: @hvd: I can certainly create an object of type `std::ostream`, e.g., using `std::ostream out(new std::filebuf("example.log"));` (note that this code requires some work to avoid a memory leak but it could be done by registering suitable callbacks).

Comment: You mentioned `ofstream`/`ostringstream` in your question, not `ostream` directly. How would it work for them?

Comment: @hvd: Based on your argument only `final` classes should be publicly movable and that is certainly not the case of other type (e.g. `std::string` or `std::vector<T>` although it is probably ill-advised to derive from these classes in the first place). I suspected that the potential of accidentally slicing streams would be the reason although the link Howard posted points at additional issues.

Comment: Oh, I'm neither saying that it should be publicly movable, nor that it shouldn't be. I'm saying I think that even if it were publicly movable, it wouldn't work for you (based on what you put in the question).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the "clearly". Streams could have been designed as refcounted pointers to stream implementation objects and that would have left them clearly copiable, assignable and swappable with an obvious semantic.

Comment: @6502: It seems a reference counted stream is something built on top of a simpler stream interface (some say it is already too complicated). In it simplest form, a reference counted stream could be implemented as `std::shared_ptr<std::ostream>` (which would also accommodate derived stream types) or it could use a derived type primarily maintaining a reference count to a stream buffer.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Originally they were movable.  This turned out to be a design flaw on my part, and discovered by Alberto Ganesh Barbati:

http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#911

The issue shows a few examples where `ostream` gets moved and/or swapped, and the results are surprising, instead of expected.  I was convinced that these types should not be publicly movable nor swappable by this issue.

Comment: Hmm. I see the problem but I’m not sure I agree that the solution is to make them non-movable. Rather, the implementations should be changed so that the code has the expected behaviour (by erasing the actual type of the stream, I’d assume). FWIW Dietmar has presented a compelling use-case for why streams *should* be movable (I’ve had the same problem before).

Comment: @KonradRudolph: The problem is that the custom stream buffer is typically embedded into the actual object rather than allocated on the heap. Mandating `std::ostream`s to be movable would mandate that the stream buffer is differently allocated which isn't viable (it could be doable for the standard stream classes but not for existing user-defined streams). I guess, the use case for returning streams of unknown type is better addressed differently.

Comment: @HowardHinnant the derived `ofstream` is still movable right?

Comment: @Koushik:  Yes, `ofstream` (and other "concrete" stream types) are movable and swappable.

Comment: I am trying to understand the logic. Besides the inconstencies shown in the link. Is correct to also say that ostreams shouldn't be movable because otherwise one could move or swap from std::cout?

Comment: That's a nice side effect, but it was never a motivating factor.  One can do pretty destructive things to `std::cout` regardless.  For example `std::cout.rdbuf(nullptr);` is still perfectly legal (but unadvisable).