# How can an std::ostream be moved?

Tags: c++, c++11, iostream

Since it is by design that [`std::ostream` can't be moved](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20774587/1120273) the question becomes: how can an `std::ostream` be moved such that it can write to different destinations?

The basic objective is to have a factory function taking a URI and returning something, let's call it, `omstream` (output movable stream) which can be used like an `std::ostream`:

```
omstream stream_factory(std::string const& uri);
void     process(std::ostream& out);

int main(int ac, char* av[]) {
    omstream destination{ stream_factory(ac == 2? av[1]: "example.txt") };
    process(destination);
}
```

The `omstream` would be responsible for properly moving the object:

```
class omstream
    : public std::ostream {
    // suitable members
public:
    omstream(/* suitable constructor arguments */);
    omstream(omstream&& other) // follow recipe of 27.9.1.11 [ofstream.cons] paragraph 4
        : std:ios(std::move(other))
        , std::ostream(std::move(other))
        // move any members {
        this->set_rdbuf(/* get the stream buffer */);
    }
    // other helpful or necessary members
};
```

The question is really what it takes to implement `omstream` (or, even a corresponding class template `basic_omstream`)?

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong, but isn't calling `std::move` on an rvalue reference a bit...redundant?

Comment: like this ? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/tie/

Comment: @chris: you mean `std::move(other)`? Well, the moment an object has a name it isn't an rvalue. In the argument list it basically indicates that an rvalue can be passed to the function but within the function the parameter is an lvalue.

Comment: @user2485710: `tie()` does something quite different: it registers the corresponding `std::ostream` as an object of interest which needs to be flushed before the stream to which it is tied can used. It doesn't help with creating a stream in a factory method and returning it.

Comment: @DietmarKühl, My bad, seems I still don't understand them as well as I should.

Comment: The implicitly private inheritance is intended? (Never seen it written implicitly..)

Comment: Is the first sentence a type-o?  The linked question says that `ostream` isn't movable.  It does *not* say that `ofstream` is not movable.  `ofstream` *is* movable.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: it should have been `std::ostream`. I have fixed the typo.

Comment: @DyP: The private inheritance wasn't intended: the goal is to have `omstream` be an `std::ostream`. I have fixed the typo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've almost got it right.  Your example is move constructing the `ios` base twice.  You should move *only* the **direct** base class.  And assuming there is member `streambuf`, move that too:

```
class omstream
    : public std::ostream {
    // suitable members
public:
    omstream(/* suitable constructor arguments */);
    omstream(omstream&& other) // follow recipe of 27.9.1.11 [ofstream.cons] paragraph 4
        : std: ostream(std::move(other)),
        // move any members {
        this->set_rdbuf(/* install the stream buffer */);
    }
    // other helpful or necessary members
};
```

I changed "get" to "install" in the `set_rdbuf` comment.  Typically this installs a pointer to the member `streambuf` into the `ios` base class.

The current unorthodox design of the move and swap members of `istream/ostream` was set up to make the move and swap members of the derived classes (such as `ofstream` and `omstream`) more intuitive.  The recipe is:

> Move the base and members, and in the move constructor set the `rdbuf`.

It is that embedded `rdbuf` that is the complicating factor for the entire hierarchy.

Comment: I entirely missed that `std::basic_ostream<...>`'s move constructor calls `std::basic_ios<...>::move()`. That is is, the call to `std::basic_ios<...>` default constructor is actually not done from `std::basic_ostream<...>` but from the most derived type as it is a `virtual` base: the statement in 27.7.3.2 [ostream.cons] paragraph 5 to call `std::basic_ios<...>`'s default constructor is part of the contract of a deriving stream!

Comment: <nod> This is confusing territory.  I have to re-learn it every time I look at it.

Answer (score 8):

The code posted in Howard's answer is a draft (based on the draft posted in the question). Howard's answer helped resolving a confusing issue with the `virtual` base class `std::ios`: the base class needs to be default constructed when moving a derived stream as the `std::ios` portion of a stream will explicitly be moved by the `std::ostream` move constructor using `std::ios::move()`. This answer merely fills in the missing bits.

The implementation below maintains a pointer to a stream buffer which normally expected to live on the heap and will be released upon destruction with the help of `std::unique_ptr<...>`. As it may be desirable to return an `std::omstream` the stream buffer of a long-lived stream, e.g., `std::cout`, the `std::unique_ptr<...>` is set up to use a deleter which may do nothing if the `omstream` doesn't own the stream buffer.

```
#include <ostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

template <typename cT, typename Traits = std::char_traits<cT>>
class basic_omstream
    : public std::basic_ostream<cT, Traits>
{
    using deleter = void (*)(std::basic_streambuf<cT, Traits>*);

    static void delete_sbuf(std::basic_streambuf<cT, Traits>* sbuf) {
        delete sbuf;
    }
    static void ignore_sbuf(std::basic_streambuf<cT, Traits>*) {
    }
    std::unique_ptr<std::basic_streambuf<cT, Traits>, deleter> m_sbuf;
public:
    basic_omstream()
        : std::basic_ios<cT, Traits>()
        , std::basic_ostream<cT, Traits>(nullptr)
        , m_sbuf(nullptr, &ignore_sbuf) {
    }
    basic_omstream(std::basic_streambuf<cT, Traits>* sbuf,
                   bool owns_streambuf)
        : std::basic_ios<cT, Traits>()
        , std::basic_ostream<cT, Traits>(sbuf)
        , m_sbuf(sbuf, owns_streambuf? &delete_sbuf: &ignore_sbuf) {
        this->set_rdbuf(this->m_sbuf.get());
    }
    basic_omstream(basic_omstream&& other)
        : std::basic_ios<cT, Traits>() // default construct ios!
        , std::basic_ostream<cT, Traits>(std::move(other))
        , m_sbuf(std::move(other.m_sbuf)) {
        this->set_rdbuf(this->m_sbuf.get());
    }
    basic_omstream& operator=(basic_omstream&& other) {
        this->std::basic_ostream<cT, Traits>::swap(other);
        this->m_sbuf.swap(other.m_sbuf);
        this->set_rdbuf(this->m_sbuf.get());
        return *this;
    }
};

typedef basic_omstream<char>    omstream;
typedef basic_omstream<wchar_t> womstream;
```

Using an `std::ofstream` or an `std::ostringstream` to initialize an `omstream` doesn't work unless the corresponding stream outlives the `omstream`. In general a corresponding stream buffer will be allocated. The class `omstream` could, e.g., be used like in the code below which create a stream based on an URI given to a suitable factory function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

omstream make_stream(std::string const& uri) {
    if (uri == "stream://stdout") {
        return omstream(std::cout.rdbuf(), false);
    }
    else if (uri == "stream://stdlog") {
        return omstream(std::clog.rdbuf(), false);
    }
    else if (uri == "stream://stderr") {
        return omstream(std::cerr.rdbuf(), false);
    }
    else if (uri.substr(0, 8) == "file:///") {
        std::unique_ptr<std::filebuf> fbuf(new std::filebuf);
        fbuf->open(uri.substr(8), std::ios_base::out);
        return omstream(fbuf.release(), true);
    }
    else if (uri.substr(0, 9) == "string://") {
        return omstream(new std::stringbuf(uri.substr(9)), true);
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("unknown URI: '" + uri + "'");
}

int main(int ac, char* av[])
{
    omstream out{ make_stream(ac == 2? av[1]: "stream://stdout") };
    out << "hello, world\n";
}
```

If there are other stream buffers available which could be constructed from a URI, these could be added to the `make_stream()` function.