# How to design a file container in C++?

Tags: c++, file, design-patterns, stream

My plan is to build a `fileContainer` that consists mainly of a `std::map` that associate specific `file`s to an `ID`. Each `file` has for attributes a `ofstream`, a path (`string`) and a few other information.

The problem is that an `ofstream` cannot be copied ([Why copying stringstream is not allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010864/why-copying-stringstream-is-not-allowed)) and cannot even be moved ([Why can't std::ostream be moved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20774587/why-cant-stdostream-be-moved)). One can therefore not create `file` objects to then `insert` them into the map of the `fileContainer`.

What I am trying to do is something like

```
file f(arguments...); // create a `file`
FC.insert(f);         // Note the FC is a global singleton of class `fileContainer`
...
{
   file& f = FC.getFile(fileID); // find a specific file in the file container
   f.open();
   f.write(s1);
   f.write(s2);
   f.write(s3);
   f.close();
}
```

I fail to see how such functionality could be achieved without having to copy or move a `stream`. Can you help me out to build this type of functionality?

**Response to @πάνταῥεῖ comment**

My code can produce about 20 different types of files. The types of files (which I above call `ID`) that are actually being produce depends upon the user input.

My goal is to have a `fileContainer` in which, I insert `file` objects. Those file objects are created while I read the input. Each `file` object match to a file `ID`. For any given `file` object a single file is being produced but for others, several files are being produced (information that can be gathered only during the process).

During the process, I would just look at whether a given `ID` is present in the `fileContainer` and if it is, then I write to it the associated file.

I already have a working version of the code, the issue is that it does not compile on every machine (looks like some compilers are fine with moving streams while others aren't)

Comment: What's the use case you want to tackle? Sounds like a XY problem for me.

Comment: Right... I understand your comment. Thanks. I tried to respond to it directly in the post (see Response to @πάνταῥεῖ comment)

Comment: Your link says that `ofstream` IS moveable, only `ostream` is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### If you only need `std::ofstream`

No problem! These *are* moveable.

---

#### If you need *any* `std::ostream`

Since `std::ostreams` cannot be copied or moved, your only option is to go back in time and store pointers instead. Use dynamic allocation to get fine control over the lifetime of your stubborn stream objects.

Abstracting away your custom container, a basic example looks like this:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::ostream>> container;
container.push_back(std::make_unique<std::ostringstream>());
container.push_back(std::make_unique<std::ofstream>("/tmp/lol"));
```

…and so forth.

Nice, huh? `#c++`

Comment: This is what I would suggest, however there is another way peculiar to iostreams.

Comment: @BenVoigt: By all means reveal the secret!

Comment: @BenVoigt: Is it something to do with stealing buffers (via `rdbuf`) in a hypothetical `file` move constructor? And is it impervious to [the problems Howard became concerned about back when streams _were_ going to be moveable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20774666/560648)?

Comment: Yeah, `rdbuf()` is exactly it.  You then have a slight problem with lifetime management of the buffer objects.  Anyway, the linked answer by Howard Hinnant says that ofstream is moveable... off to check that.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yeah I think the problems with that are why `std::ostream` _isn't_ moveable.

Comment: Another option is to store `filebuf` objects in the map (they're moveable) and let the streams be transient (temporarily associated to the `filebuf`, then detached and the stream gets destroyed while the `filebuf` remains)

Comment: @BenVoigt: That's not terrible