# Can I store a collection of iostreams without manually allocating them on the heap?

Tags: c++

In C++, `std::basic_iostream`'s copy- and move-assignment operators are protected (for reasons I don't really understand).  This seems to leave me without many ways of managing a collection of `iostream` objects, short of manually allocating them on the heap, storing a list of pointers, and writing a destructor that cleans them up.

Am I missing some trick that would let me allocate them inside of, say, a `std::vector`?

Of course I suppose I could inherit and just promote the protected operator to public, but that seems like a whole mess.

**Bonus question**: Why <s>are these methods</s> is the move-assignment operator protected in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, but could you explain *why* you downvoted?

Comment: Do you know the number of streams at compile time?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I don't.

Comment: Still requires dynamic allocation but `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<stream_type>>` keeps you from having to do an manual memory management.

Comment: Regarding your _"Bonus question"_ see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903903/c-copy-a-stream-object

Comment: Try to think about what it logically means, to copy an input or an output stream. It makes no sense, whatsoever. Are both input streams, the original one, and the copy, reading from the same file? Same file position? Different file positions? What about if the underlying input stream is a pipe? What about all the internal buffering input streams do, via `std::streambuf`? Ditto for output streams. Big mess. And that's why you cannot copy them.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury _"I don't"_ Well I can't see any way without involving heap allocation  then.

Comment: Related question [Why can't std::ostream be moved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20774587/why-cant-stdostream-be-moved).

Comment: Streams are movable, but you can't store base classes by value. A `std::basic_iostream` is a base type and having an actual `basic_iostream` (as opposed to a concrete type like `ofstream` posing as a `basic_iostream`) would not make sense If you want to do that, you fall into polymorphism where you pretty much have to use dynamic allocation (usually `std::unique_ptr`s).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: It's not an abstract class, and I've been constructing and using `std::iostream` instances directly in my code.  Is there some reason I shouldn't?

Comment: @DanielMcLaury I mean, it'll compile and work. But as you noticed from the protected members it's really designed to be derived. My impression was that you were asking for a container to store instances of derived types, but I guess I misunderstood.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: If you write that up as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of closing this out, I'll summarize François Andrieux's comments, which add up to a resolution to the question:

Even though `std::iostream` is not an abstract class and can be instantiated and used, it's not *intended* to be; instead, you're supposed to inherit from it to build your own streams.  You can then implement move constructors and put these into a `std::vector` or whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I store a collection of iostreams anywhere other than the heap?

The only standard container that doesn't allocate dynamically is `std::array`. You can store `iostream`'s in an array:

```
std::stringbuf sb;
std::array streams{
    std::iostream(&sb),
    std::iostream(&sb),
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::fstream> * v = new std::vector<std::fstream> (2);

  (*v)[0].open("/tmp/0", std::ios_base::out);
  (*v)[1].open("/tmp/1", std::ios_base::out);

  (*v)[0] << "000" << std::endl;
  (*v)[1] << "111" << std::endl;

  delete v;
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wextra s.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ rm -f 0 1
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ls -l 0 1
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 4 févr. 21 18:39 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 4 févr. 21 18:39 1
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat 0 1
000
111
```

Comment: Would involve heap allocation though, which I read the OP want's to avoid (for some unclear reason).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ah yes, ok in the heap now, agree about unclear reason, and the internal vector is in the heap in all cases, only the 'envelope' can be in the stack

Comment: Okay, I see that the underlying issue is that std::iostream was designed to be derived from rather than used directly.

Comment: @bruno The standard term for _evelope_ is _container_.